Type gettting marked as nullable even when explicitly stated it can't be nullable
I'm using Nexus.js library for GraphQL query, mutation and types generation.
My nexus types are getting generated in typings.ts file and looks like the following:
Query: {
    UserSearch: NexusGenRootTypes['UserConnection'];
}

UserConnection: { // field return type
    edges: Array<NexusGenRootTypes['UserEdge'] | null> | null; // [UserEdge]
    pageInfo: NexusGenRootTypes['PageInfo']; // PageInfo!
}
UserEdge: { // field return type
    cursor: string; // String!
    node: NexusGenRootTypes['User'] | null; // User
}

Where type of node in UserEdge supposed to just best NexusGenRootTypes['User'], it's generating as NexusGenRootTypes['User'] | null
In the older version of nexus it was working fine as it was generating type as NexusGenRootTypes['User'] only.
I was using nexus version - 0.12.0-rc.13
And when i have upgraded my code and nexus version to 1.3.0, it has raised this problem
I have also tried to give nulllable: false in my UserSearch queryField, but it didn't work.
